# Change code from mysql to mssql in a php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm new to php and sql.

The codes below are written in php and working fine when connecting to a mysql database. SELECT query is working and UPDATE query is working.

But when connecting to an mssql database, the codes don't work well.
I need to convert them to connect to a similar mssql database.
Thank you.

---

```
 <table id="data_table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Age</th>    
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        $sql_query = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, address, email FROM 
     myguests LIMIT 10";
        $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database 
     error:". mysqli_error($conn));
        while( $developer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        ?>
           <tr id="<?php echo $developer ['id']; ?>">
           <td><?php echo $developer ['id']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $developer ['firstname']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $developer ['lastname']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $developer ['address']; ?></td>   
           <td><?php echo $developer ['email']; ?></td>

               </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

---

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "*****";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "*****";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or 
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
  }
 ?>
```

---

```
   <?php
   include_once("db_connect.php");
   $input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
   if ($input['action'] == 'edit') {    
    $update_field='';
   if(isset($input['firstname'])) {
    $update_field.= "firstname='".$input['firstname']."'";
    } else if(isset($input['lastname'])) {
    $update_field.= "lastname='".$input['lastname']."'";
   } else if(isset($input['address'])) {
    $update_field.= "address='".$input['address']."'";
     } else if(isset($input['email'])) {
    $update_field.= "email='".$input['email']."'";

       }    
        if($update_field && $input['id']) {
        $sql_query = "UPDATE myguests SET $update_field WHERE id='" . 
          $input['id'] . "'";   
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:". 
          mysqli_error($conn));     
              }
              }
```

Comment: Go into detail which concrete conversion issues or errors you ran into. Some attempts wouldn't go amiss. Else people could get the impression you're merely passing on *your* rewriting job.

Comment: How do you intend to connect to SQL Server and what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: "...don't work well..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough equivalent of MySQL `LIMIT` in SQL Server is `TOP`, so you may try something like:

```
SELECT TOP 10 id, firstname, lastname, address, email
FROM myguests
ORDER BY <some_column>;
```

Note carefully that I added an `ORDER BY` clause to your query.  Using `LIMIT` (or `TOP`) without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless, because you haven't told SQL *which* 10 rows you want, relative to some ordering.

Comment: Thank you. I think there are other codes which need changing.

Comment: @SadiMishal You need to stop using MySQL specific methods. Switch to SQL Server library in PHP